# How to set focus for div inside parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#container2").focus();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mainwrapper">
        <!-- container1 -->
        <div id="container1" 
             style="height:100px;width:299px;">
            First Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text1 
        </div>

        <!-- container2 -->
        <div id="container2"  style="height:100px;width:299px;">
            Second Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text2
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

this is my html code,when page loads focus should on second div,but this is not working ,help me how to do this,thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean focus? You mean scroll to it?

Comment: div's do not have focus, unless they are contenteditable.

Comment: focus means here hover

Comment: You want the mouse pointer to be on that element?

Comment: I need hover focus on that div

Comment: @user3467244 "hover focus"? What is that? Just give a `tabindex` to the `#container2` and your script will work as it is. In Chrome you can actually [see an outline](http://jsfiddle.net/44s4e/) around the div when you open your page. If that is not what you want, please elaborate your question.

Comment: yes need an outline for div2 when page loads

Comment: When this outline should go away then?

Comment: when body onload outline should present on div2,that it i need,please help me

Comment: when the cursor moves to other divs hover(outline) should change to respective div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably does what you need. At first, set `class="borderonload"` to `#container2`, then add the CSS below:

```
#mainwrapper div:hover, .borderonload {
    border: 2px solid #aaf;
}
```

In script:

```
$('#mainwrapper').on('mousemove', function (e) {
    var $cont2 = $('#container2');
    if (e.target !== $cont2) {
        $cont2.removeClass('borderonload');
        $('#mainwrapper').off('mousemove');
    }
});
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ELC6t/2/).

Comment: @user3467244 That was fast, thanks : ). I've improved the code, now it removes the useless event listener too.

Answer (score 0):

`.focus()` is not going to scroll to specified div.use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#container2').offset().top }, 'slow');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LMp8J/)**

Comment: i dont need scroll ,i need hover focus on container2

Comment: @user3467244:whoa... whats hover focus??

Comment: need an outline for div2 when page loads

Comment: @user3467244:you can do that by setting border.like this  http://jsfiddle.net/LMp8J/4/